Flutter container borderRadius , white background
Im using a container for a bottom navbar. The navbar has borderradius
borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(30))

But when the border radius is circular i'm getting a white background where the curve is. I've tried changing background color to transparent, but it doesn't remove that white color. instead it changes the container color. Also i've tried Cliprrect. How can i remove it?


If your are  using a container for a bottom navbar.
Make sure you are using stack to show the navbar

Use stack and place bottom navigation bar at bottom
